# how can i pass a Blob element from javascript to oracle apex item?

Tags: javascript, oracle, blob, oracle-apex

I am new to ORACLE APEX and I am trying to convert URL of Pictures to blobs and insert them in my database

I have writed this code :

```
fetch(Link)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.blob()
  })
  .then(function(blob) {

  document.getElementById("ITEM").value = blob;

  });
```

The "ITEM" element is a display image, source : BLOB column.

I've tried this without any luck

How can i pass the value to an item so i can call the item when i write my insert command in sql ?

Comment: *"I've tried this without any luck"* is rather unclear. Please explain what **actually happens**. For instance, do you get an error message?

Comment: Afaik, APEX really only provides one easy way to insert/update blob columns: use a **file browser** page item. If you don't want to do that, you'll probably have to write your own application process and call it from a dynamic action. The tricky part will be passing binary data from your dynamic action / ajax request to your pl/sql application process. I'd probably use base64.

Comment: @APC when i pass the blob to the item i don't get nothing, if the ITEM is a text field i get a string "[object blob] and if the ITEM is a display image, nothing happens.

Comment: @kfinity thanks for your answer, i can't use a file browser because i don't upload the pictures from my desktop but with a get request to another server and the response is the Image Url in return. from ajax to pl sql with base64 ? how can i do that ? i mean i tried to convert the blob to Hex and do an insert but i stil don't know how to do it

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I bet you'll save yourself time with this https://github.com/Dani3lSun/apex-plugin-dropzone

Comment: Based on your last comment, perhaps you're chasing utl_http

Comment: @Scott thanks for your answer, i still can't use utl_http, because I'm waiting for my boss to give me ACL rights so i can make http requests with PL/SQL. 
I am trying to save a Blob(image) into my database and i only have a Url of the image

Answer (score 0):

You should use APEX JavaScript API for this, you can look here for more information:

- [Official APEX JS API Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/AEXJS/global.html)
- [Example of its usage for getting and setting APEX items values](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/6341/index-en.html)

For your case your code snippet would look like this:

```
fetch(myLink)
  .then(function(myResponse) {
    return myResponse.blob()
  })
  .then(function(myBlob) {
      $s("ITEM_NAME", myBlob)
  });
```

Here is the live demo: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=BLOB_ITEM_TEST
What happens there - after page load the image is fetched into the `P1_BLOB_ITEM` item. You can check it using your browser development tools by watching one of the following expressions: `$v("P1_BLOB_ITEM")` or `apex.item("P1_BLOB_ITEM").getValue()`.

Comment: HI, I'm very thankful for your response, i still have a question though, what should the item actually be (DISPLAY IMAGE, Text Field, hidden .. etc )?

Comment: `Hidden` would fit, I suppose

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the BLOB, you can use JavaScript native File and DataTransfer APIs. Then, you can change the page item, which needs to be of file type. Note that in my case, the item ID is **P200_BLOB_HOLDER**.

```
var file = new File([blob], "test.pdf");
console.log(file);
let container = new DataTransfer();
container.items.add(file);
#("input#P200_BLOB_HOLDER")[0].files = container.files;
```

Afterward, you can use PL/SQL to process the files from the **apex_application_temp_files** table.